# Direct2D (SharpDX) block compressed bitmaps not compressed in memory

Tags: c#, direct2d, sharpdx, dds-format

I have a few (8-10) large texture atlases (around 8192x8192 saved as BC1 DDS) but they are rather small disk space wise, only 32MiB.

The problem is, that when I load those files using WIC, they lose their block compression and take up to 256MiB of RAM, which shouldn't happen according to the [sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/Direct2D/block-compression)

Here is my C# SharpDX code which loads the file:

```
public Bitmap LoadBitmap(string path) {
    Bitmap m;

    using (BitmapDecoder d = new BitmapDecoder(imagingFactory, $"plugins/HDPatch/{path}", Guid.Empty, SharpDX.IO.NativeFileAccess.Read, DecodeOptions.CacheOnDemand)) {
        DdsDecoder decoder = d.QueryInterface<DdsDecoder>();
        decoder.GetFrame(0, 0, 0, out BitmapFrameDecode frame);
        m = SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap.FromWicBitmap(_target, frame);//_target.CreateBitmap(converter, new BitmapProperties());
        decoder.Dispose();
        frame.Dispose();
    }

    return m;
}
```

Do I need to change something, or should I use a different method of loading them than WIC?

I looked at the [DdsFrameDecode.CopyBlocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nf-wincodec-iwicddsframedecode-copyblocks) (+ [ID2D1Bitmap::CopyFromMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1bitmap-copyfrommemory)) method but I do not know how that works.. (What exactly is my stride and where do I get that information from)

EDIT:

So the BitmapFrameDecode gives me a PixelFormat of 32bppPBGRA

If I query a DDSFrameDecode from that BitmapFrameDecode, I get a format of BC1_UNorm from the DdsFrameDecode. The DdsDecoder also reports a texture with DdsAlphaModePremultiplied, and a DxgiFormat of BC1_UNorm.

But when I force the pixel format of BC1_UNorm in the BitmapProperties I get the D2D DEBUG ERROR: "The pixel format passed to this API is not compatible with the pixel format of the IWICBitmapSource"

EDIT2:
I figured out how to use CopyBlocks

```
    SharpDX.DataStream stream = new 
    SharpDX.DataStream(test2.FormatInfo.BytesPerBlock * test2.SizeInBlocks.Width * test2.SizeInBlocks.Height, true, true);
    test2.CopyBlocks(null, test2.FormatInfo.BytesPerBlock * test2.SizeInBlocks.Width, stream);
    m = new Bitmap(_target, new SharpDX.Size2(decoder.Parameters.Width, decoder.Parameters.Height), stream, test2.FormatInfo.BytesPerBlock * test2.FormatInfo.BlockWidth, new BitmapProperties(new PixelFormat(SharpDX.DXGI.Format.BC1_UNorm, AlphaMode.Premultiplied)));
```

But the problem still exists. It can successfully create the Bitmap but it still consumes to much memory (250MiB+ instead of the actual block compressed size of 32MiB)

Does it maybe have to do with the render target of?
I use a software B8G8R8A8_UNorm DeviceContext render target

EDIT3:

Example project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hCgQnEV9xcTevgdswAiPJNREk1oDgqDC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: As doc'd here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/Direct2D/block-compression#direct2d-apis CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap is supposed to do the work by itself, but since you're using sharpdx, not sure what it does undercovers. You may want to try to specify a D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES1 you can also check what is  the characteristics of the objects: decoder, frame, bitmap, etc.

Comment: @SimonMourier So the BitmapFrameDecode gives me a PixelFormat of 32bppPBGRA
If I query a DDSFrameDecode from that BitmapFrameDecode, I get a format of BC1_UNorm from the DdsFrameDecode. The DdsDecoder also reports a texture with DdsAlphaModePremultiplied, and the DxgiFormat of BC1_UNorm.

Problem is, when I force the pixel format of BC1_UNorm in the BitmapProperties I get the D2D DEBUG ERROR: "The pixel format passed to this API is not compatible with the pixel format of the IWICBitmapSource"

Comment: Are you using Windows 8.1 or higher? Do you have any reproducing project?

Comment: @SimonMourier I am using Windows 10 [Version 10.0.19041.746]. Here is a link for a cut together project https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hCgQnEV9xcTevgdswAiPJNREk1oDgqDC/view?usp=sharing

The example .dds is in the Build/Debug/ Folder

Comment: The DDS decoder only uses the original 32M. What allocates the CPU memory is the new in-memory Bitmap(8192x8192x4) => 268K.

Comment: But isn't this dds import process designed to save memory by having the bitmap share that block compression in memory? So that the bitmap also only consumes 32MiB or did I read something wrong? The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/Direct2D/block-compression#when-to-use-block-compression) say "You should consider using block compressed images in your app instead of other formats such as JPEG if you want to reduce the memory consumption of bitmaps" - directly referencing the memory consumption. @SimonMourier

Comment: The import process does saves memory, but that doesn't change the fact you're allocating a 8192x8192x4 bitmap from RAM. It all depends on what you do with this compressed data. You can pass raw/compressed data using CopyBlocks or uncompressed data using CopyPixels.